# Select data if no match found in second table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables. t1 contains business info:

> t1
>
> ---
>
> id    |  busName    |    busPhone

t2 contains business hours

> t2
>
> ---
>
> id    |    busId   |   open   |   close

Where t1.id = t2.busId

I need to create a query and loop through it and if t2 does not have corresponding records, select those in order to add data. Clearly the query below is incorrect...

```
SELECT t1.id
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON (t1.id = t2.busId)
WHERE t2.id != ''
```

Comment: consider `NULL` not empty string for missing records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be your query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(t1.id)
t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON (t1.id = t2.busId)
WHERE t2.busId IS NULL
```

Comment: This query works, but with about 15K records in t1 and 50K rows in t2 this literally takes minutes to return results. I wonder if it's possible to speed it up.

Comment: @santa I would recommend to add index on foreign keys, that'll speed up the query. Here in your case, you'll need an index on `busId` field of `t2` table. Check if it reduces query running time.

Answer (score 0):

```
select id from t1 where id not in (select busId  from t2)
```